# Moving website back-end to use REST API instead of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, rest, api, lumen

we are working on refactoring our framework for a website to use our own REST API instead of MySQL queries. The API uses Lumen. Some of the issues we're facing right now is there are a ton of very complex queries which we need to refactor to use our API.

The API has some basic filtering options, such as using `Like`, `In`, `Greater Than` etc. But there is no way for us to do JOINS, Aggregates, Conditional Operators, etc.

I want to know how you guys would go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used Eloquent ORM. In my opinion, you will be able to easily get through with Eloquent. It's from same people of Lumen and will probably work with no issues.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Queries Docs have some solutions to issues you have mentioned.

https ://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Hope this helps :)